# How to kill all processes using a given GPU?

Tags: kill, gpu

I use the CUDA toolkit to perform some computations on my Nvidia GPUs. How to kill all processes that use a given GPU? (killing at once, i.e. without having to manually type the PIDs behind `kill -9`.)

E.g. killing all processes using GPU 2:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the Unix philosophy, you have a tool that lists processes using a given GPU, and a tool that kills processes. Combine them using shell constructs and text processing tools.

For example, to kill all the processes using GPU 2, you can execute the following command:

```
kill $(nvidia-smi | awk '$2=="Processes:" {p=1} p && $2 == 2 && $3 > 0 {print $3}')
```

or

```
kill $(nvidia-smi -g 2 | awk '$2=="Processes:" {p=1} p && $3 > 0 {print $3}')
```

Comment: $ kill $(nvidia-smi -g 1 | awk '$2=="Processes:" {p=1} p && $3 > 0 {print $3}')
bash: kill: GPU: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: It did not worked for me, I guess there is syntax issue.

Comment: the commands don't work

Comment: Din't work => "kill: not enough arguments" ??

Comment: @Anh-ThiDINH You'll get "not enough arguments" if the `nvidia-smi` command doesn't produce any output or produces output in a different format. I don't have a machine with an NVidia GPU at hand right now to test. Maybe the format of the output has changed since I wrote this answer. Check what `nvidia-smi` prints and adapt the awk code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
lsof /dev/nvidia* | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} kill {}
```

worked for me.

In my case, the processes were not listed from `nvidia-smi`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354257/can-i-stop-all-processes-using-cuda-in-linux-without-rebooting

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you need:

```
kill -9 $(nvidia-smi | awk '$2 == "GPU" && $3 == "PID" {flag = 1} flag && $3 > 0 {print $2, $3}' | awk '$1 == 2 {print $2}')
```

For more complex conditions, you can change the condition statements of 2nd `awk` command. For example, the following command can be used to kill all processes that use GPU-0 to GPU-3 and PID > 1000:

```
kill -9 $(nvidia-smi | awk '$2 == "GPU" && $3 == "PID" {flag = 1} flag && $3 > 0 {print $2, $3}' | awk '$1 < 4 && $2 > 1000 {print $2}')
```

As you can see, `kill -9 PIDs` needs PIDs to shut processes down, and `awk` is used twice to find valid PIDs to kill.

More specifically, The 1st `awk` command will choose lines after the "GPU  PID  Type Process Name" line, and then print out lines of GPU ids and PIDs, with a space between each GPU id and PID. The 2nd `awk` will find specific GPU ids or PIDs, which in this case is to find all processes using GPU-2, and then print out the PID. Finally, `kill -9 PIDs` will kill the processes according to these PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like answer by @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' is extracting PID by `$3 > 0` but it won't work on some versions of `awk`. My workaround is checking by `$3 + 0 == $3`, which is stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421403/11501255). And here's the modified version:

`kill $(nvidia-smi -g 2 | awk '$2=="Processes:" {p=1} p && $3 + 0 == $3 {print $3}')`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
kill $(nvidia-smi -g 2 | awk '$5=="PID" {p=1} p {print $5}')
```

where the `-g` sets the gpu id to kill processes in and `$5` is the PID column. You can omit the `-g` argument if you want to kill processes in all the gpus.

The awk-ification can by further enhanced by conditioning on the gpu memory usage: `awk '$5==“PID” && $8>0 {p=1} p {print $5}'`, where `$8` is the memory usage column.